Laravel model embed nested model when just attribute appended
Need to append calculate attribute into model:
class Field extends Model {
//...
    protected $appends = ['typename'];
//...
    public function getTypenameAttribute(): string {
        return $this->type->name;
    }
}

Model dump shows me the following:
{
    "id": "9bc5b05b-46cf-470d-a848-cdb60aec2213",
    "name": "Показание термометра",
    "default": true,
    "twin_id": "9bc5b05b-3df3-4efd-8ce0-7a30be87af72",
    "type_id": "9bc3cea3-47e6-4ef2-a78f-347d51abbe3d",
    "created_at": "2024-04-10T07:21:36.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2024-04-10T07:21:36.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "origin": "thermo",
    "typename": "Целочисленное без знака",
    "type": {
      "id": "9bc3cea3-47e6-4ef2-a78f-347d51abbe3d",
      "name": "Целочисленное без знака",
      "influx_type": "uint",
      "created_at": "2024-04-09T08:54:37.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2024-04-09T08:54:37.000000Z",
      "deleted_at": null
    }
  }

typename calculated ok.
But I don't want to include nested type object. My model class not contain any $with, so this object completely unexpected.
How to exclude this nested object from dump?

You have to load the related model in order to get the type name though right? Even without a with (which is an "eager" load) when you do $this->type Laravel will perform a "lazy" load if the relationship has not been loaded already and once it's loaded it's there.

well the typename has to be loaded from somewhere right? And why are you concerned with what is dumped? If you want to control a json response use a JsonResource, don't mess around with the model class

Please make sure that you model relationship looks like something this
class Field extends Model {
// List of attributes to append to JSON serialization
protected $appends = ['typename'];

// List of attributes or relations to hide from JSON serialization
protected $hidden = ['type'];

// Getter for the appended attribute
public function getTypenameAttribute(): string {
    return $this->type->name;
}


public function type() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Type::class, 'type_id');
}

}
Usage
$field = Field::find(1); //replace your id


while this solves the issue, it is not recommended to do these type of global modifications as when you will actually want to show the related type model you will not be able to without major refactoring
